# Using Cayley-Hamilton theorem to find the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> I need to find the minimal polynomial of $\beta = i + \sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ using Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

So far I've found that $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}, i, \sqrt[3]{2}i, \sqrt[3]{4}i\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},i]$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, the matrix representing the multiplication by $\beta$ using this basis is
$$
          A = 
          \begin{pmatrix}
            0& 0& 2&-1& 0& 0\\
            1& 0& 0& 0&-1& 0\\
            0& 1& 0& 0& 0&-1\\
            1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 2\\
            0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0\\
            0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0\\
          \end{pmatrix}
$$

where the element $$\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}\sqrt[3]{2} + \lambda_{3}\sqrt[3]{4} + \lambda_{4}i + \lambda_{5}\sqrt[3]{2}i + \lambda_{6}\sqrt[3]{4}i$$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},i]$ is represented by the vector
$$
          \begin{pmatrix}
            \lambda_{1}\\
            \lambda_{2}\\
            \lambda_{3}\\
            \lambda_{4}\\
            \lambda_{5}\\
            \lambda_{6}\\
          \end{pmatrix}.
$$

I could't figure out how to use the characteristic polynomial of $A$ ($p(x) = x^{6} + 3x^{4} - 4x^{3} + 3x^{2}$) to find a polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f(\beta) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The charactestic polynomial should be $p(x)=x^6 + 3 x^4 - 4 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 12 x + 5.$ You need to check if $p$ is irreducible. There are many standard algorithm to check if a polynomial is irreducible and you can use them. Otherwise you can use sagemath or any other tools to check as done here [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwL0rOpsFOwVQjIz6nMy8_NTMwJysxL1wgM1OTlKsjPAcpUxJkpaCsYK2gBWSYKugomIIYxSAjEMAIyDI2ALCBtCtail1kcn1lUlJpSmpyZlJOqoQkAV1cbTg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: I have used an online calculator : [here](https://mathforyou.net/en/online/matrices/charpoly/?e0=MAA1&e1=MAA1&e2=MgA1&e3=LQAxAA2&e4=MAA1&e5=MAA1&e6=MQA1&e7=MAA1&e8=MAA1&e9=MAA1&e10=LQAxAA2&e11=MAA1&e12=MAAgAA2&e13=MQA1&e14=MAA1&e15=MAA1&e16=MAA1&e17=LQAxAA2&e18=MQA1&e19=MAA1&e20=MAA1&e21=MAA1&e22=MAA1&e23=MgA1&e24=MAA1&e25=MQA1&e26=MAA1&e27=MQA1&e28=MAA1&e29=MAA1&e30=MAA1&e31=MAA1&e32=MQA1&e33=MAA1&e34=MQA1&e35=MAA1&o0=6&o1=6&o2=1&s=54&i=0&h=5C4037D3AF0F86D6160C1E696969237D), you may verify.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to use H-C Theorem for finding the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @user26857 Well, the char. polynomial of $A$ was found using H-C theorem even though I have used an online tool to verify.